# Notify a JButton to know which was changed

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, actionlistener

I have created separate stored procedures for every update action on my components.

Here are the stored procedures:

```
updateCurriculumName() --call only if name was changed
updateCurriculumYearLevel() --call only if year level was changed
updateCurriculumSchoolYear() -- call only if school year was changed
updateCurriculumDescription() -- call only if description was changed
updateCurriculumSubjects() -- call only if there are changes made on assigned subjects
```

I need to be able to notify the `SAVE` button for it to know which component was modified/changed so that it will know which procedure to call and not call all procedures.

For instance, if only the curriculum's name was changed, therefore, it should only call the `updateCurriculumName()` procedure.

Notice I mark the JLabel's text with `*` if changes were made to a JTextField or JComboBox or JTextArea.

I currently have,

`DocumentListener` for **Curriculum Name** `JTextField` (which adds the `*`)

`ItemStateChangedListener` for **Year Level** `JComboBox` (also adds the `*`)

`ItemStateChangedListener` for **School Year** `JComboBox` (also adds the `*` )

How can I tell SAVE button's `actionPerformed` instructions to call "only" the stored procedure(s) for components whose state / value was changed?

Like,

```
private void SaveJbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

if(yearlevel was changed)
call updateYearLevel()
else if(curriculumName was changed)
call updateCurriculumName()
else if(schoolyear was changed)
call updateCurriculumSchoolYear() 

}
```

[image]

I'd appreciate any advice or suggestion of what approach is best.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One approach is to store a boolean for each procedure. Change it to `true` when the corresponding data is changed. When the button is clicked, only do those procedures for which the `xDataChanged` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

There is some options to do so:

1. add listener to the button, and add booleans to each of the procedures:

   ```
   mSaveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if (updateName) {
               updatename();
           }

           if (updateYearLevel) {
                updateYearLevel();
           }

           ...
       }
   });
   ```
2. You can create a custom `save` button, and pass to the button the booleans when the button is trigger:

   ```
   public class SaveBtn extends JButton {

       public SaveBtn(final boolean updateName, final boolean   
       updateYearLevel...) {

           if (updateName) {
               updatename();
           }

           if (updateYearLevel) {
               updateYearLevel();
           }

           ...

       } 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an object for either each relevant partition of your view or for the whole view itself. Put all relevant variables with the associated getters and setters in it.

For example:

```
class ViewObject{
      private String curriculumName;
      public void setCurriculumName(String curriculumName){...}
      public String getCurriculumName(){...}
      //...and so on
}
```

Use this object as transfer object between the controller/model and the view. So for example load an initial version containing data or an empty one (depending on the Use-Case) when the view is loaded/created. Afterwards, the user modifies the fields in the view and when the user clicks save put the values of your view into it and pass it to the saving/processing component.
If it's important to know what exactly changed than create a new one, on save click, which holds the view data and compare it to the initial one.

I'm sure that this approach will reduce the complexity of your program a lot and it will save you from future trouble associated to the tight binding between view and logic, hence view and controller.